# Calculate mean across a row of an array using a row of a masking array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, octave

In converting this simple line of Octave code to Python, I’m wondering if there's a quicker/cleaner way:

Given two matrices, the Octave command averages a row of matrix `Y` using a Boolean matrix `R` to tag the values that are of interest:

```
load (‘mydata.mat’)
row1_mean = mean( Y(1, R(1, :) ) )
```

Nice and quick and easy. Trying to do that in Python is much less succinct, but so far I can get there like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import io as spio

myDict = spio.loadmat(‘mydata.mat’)
Y_mat = myDict['Y']
R_mat = myDict['R']

maskR = ~R_mat.astype(bool)[0][:]                      # row as boolean so we can invert it
maskR = maskR.astype(int)                              # turn it back to 1s & 0s

maskedY = np.ma.masked_array(Y_mat[0][:], mask=maskR)  # mask row of Y with R matrix

row1_mean = maskedY.mean()                             # get the mean
```

I’m probably missing a better approach.
Particularly, is there an easier way to invert a matrix of 1s and 0s? 
Maybe too there's a more direct way to get a mean of an array slice (I know about `axis`) but taking into account a masking array?

Comment: Can you give a sample input and expected output?

Comment: invert an array of 1s and 0s: `1 - arr` or `1 ^ arr` or `np.array([1, 0])[arr]`

Comment: You may want to convert the following expression that gives a vector containing means of each row: `row_mean = sum(Y .* R, 2) ./ sum(R, 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use masked arrays, here is a streamlined way of doing that:

```
import numpy as np

# create some mock data
R_mat = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
Y_mat = np.random.randint(0, 2, (4, 4))

R_mat
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15]])
Y_mat
# array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0]])

# compute all row means or all column means at once
# use Y_mat==0 to invert and convert to bool in one go
row_means = np.ma.MaskedArray(R_mat, Y_mat==0).mean(axis=1)
col_means = np.ma.MaskedArray(R_mat, Y_mat==0).mean(axis=0)

row_means
# masked_array(data=[2.0, 5.5, 10.0, 14.0],
#              mask=[False, False, False, False],
#        fill_value=1e+20)
col_means
# masked_array(data=[--, 5.0, 10.0, 7.0],
#              mask=[ True, False, False, False],
#        fill_value=1e+20)


# or take just one row or column and get the mean 
np.ma.MaskedArray(R_mat, Y_mat==0)[2].mean()
# 10.0
np.ma.MaskedArray(R_mat, Y_mat==0)[:, 0].mean()
# masked
```

If for some reason you want to avoid masked arrays:

```
nrow, ncol = R_mat.shape

I, J = np.where(Y_mat)
row_means = np.bincount(I, R_mat[I, J], nrow) / np.bincount(I, None, nrow)

J, I = np.where(Y_mat.T)
col_means = np.bincount(J, R_mat[I, J], ncol) / np.bincount(J, None, ncol)
# __main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

row_means
# array([ 2. ,  5.5, 10. , 14. ])
col_means
# array([nan,  5., 10.,  7.])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Take the masked mean with Numpy

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, here's a much better way:

```
row1_mean = Y_mat[0][R_mat[0].astype(bool)].mean()
```

That's if you just want the mean of a single row. You can calculate the means for every row like this:

```
means = np.nanmean(np.where(mask, arr, np.nan), axis=1)
# if every value in a given row is masked, the mean will be calculated as nan. Change those to zeros
means[np.isnan(means)] = 0
```

## Boolean indexing in Numpy

As a note for future use, you actually can index a Numpy array with a boolean array (just like Octave, I guess?). Here's a brief example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10*5).reshape(10,5)
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 5), dtype=bool)

print('original array\n%s\n' % arr)
print('boolean masked array\n%s\n' % arr[mask])
```

Output:

```
original array
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49]]

boolean masked array
[ 1  2  3  4  7  8 10 11 12 14 15 19 26 27 29 33 38 39 44 45 46]
```

As you can see, boolean indexing will flatten a 2D array (for reasons explained by Paul Panzer in the comments). This is why I used `np.where` in my second answer above.

Comment: I don't think the second will work because assuming Y_mat and R_mat have the same shape boolean indexing will result in a flat array. It has to because in general the number of Trues i.e. the size of the resulting array can be anything.

Comment: I hate to be a nuisance but I think OP wants to drop the masked values, not zero them. That makes a difference in the denominator of the mean.

Comment: I'm always glad for the feedback. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: Octave also flattens the array with Boolean indexing, so `arr[mask]` is actually the equivalent of the code in the question.

Comment: Nice - didn't know about indexing an array with an array, exp a bool one. Good info.